# In SQLAlchemy ORM, How do I get the primary key columns for use in session.query().group_by()?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

## Question

How do I get a list of all primary key columns of a model class and all its parents in the polymorphic hierarchy, so I can use it in a `session.query().group_by`?

## Details

In SQLAlchemy ORM, if I'm querying a class that is part of a polymorphic hierarchy and I want to `GROUP BY` it's primary key, I must also `GROUP BY` all primary keys of its parents in the polymorphic hierarchy.

Imagine the following setup inspired by the [Mapping Class Inheritance Hierarchies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) section of the sqlalchemy documentation:

```py
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }

class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'engineer'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    engineer_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'engineer',
    }

class EngineeringTask(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'engineering_task'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

    assigned_engineer_id = Column(ForeignKey(Engineer.id))
    assigned_engineer = relationship(Engineer, backref=backref("assigned_tasks", lazy="dynamic"))
```

If I want to do a query like

```
session.query(
    Engineer,
).join(
    Engineer.assigned_tasks,
).add_columns(
    func.count(EngineeringTask.id).label('assigned_task_count'),
).group_by(Engineer.id, Employee.id)
```

Such a query, which is selecting all columns from `Engineer` and `Employee` but not aggregating them, is possible in PostgreSQL [because](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) (emphasis mine):

> When `GROUP BY` is present (...) it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions or **when the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns**, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the **primary key** of the table containing the ungrouped column.

But it requires that I know / care / remember all the primary key columns of the mapped class I'm selecting and all it's parents in the polymorphic hierarchy (`Engineer.id` and `Employee.id` in this case)

How can I obtain the list of all the primary key columns of `Engineer` and all parents in the polymorphic hierarchy, dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could come up with so far is this function:

```py
from sqlalchemy import inspect

def polymorphic_primary_keys(cls): 
    mapper = inspect(cls)
    yield from (column for column in mapper.columns if column.primary_key) 
    if mapper.inherits is not None: 
        yield from polymorphic_primary_keys(mapper.inherits.entity)
```

Use it like this:

```py
query = session.query(
    Engineer,
).join(
    Engineer.assigned_tasks,
).add_columns(
    func.count(EngineeringTask.id).label('assigned_task_count'),
).group_by(*polymorphic_primary_keys(Engineer))
```

Where `inspect(Engineer)` returns `Engineer.__mapper__` which is a [`Mapper`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper) containing:

- [`Mapper.columns`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.columns), an iterator/dictionary/attribute accessor of the columns of the mapped model
- [`Mapper.inherits`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.inherits), which is the mapper of the parent entity, if any.

It's unsatisfying for a few reasons:

- There is [`Mapper.primary_key`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.primary_key) which is supposed to be an iterator over the primary keys, but I can't use it since it returns the primary keys of the topmost parent, not the currently mapped entity, so I have to iterate over `Mapper.columns` and check `primary_key` attribute.
- There is a [`Mapper.polymorphic_iterator()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.polymorphic_iterator) method and a [`Mapper.self_and_descendants`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.self_and_descendants) attribute that both return an iterator containing the current mapper and the mappers of all "downstream" subclasses of the current entity. Why isn't there an equivalent iterator for the "upstream" superclasses?

But it gets the job done...